# Repeat down a column with an unequal number of values

Tags: r

I would like to repeat values down a column that may not have the same amount of repeats.

For example, I would like to create a column named "Week"  where I have "Week 1" repeat 10 times, then "week 2" repeat 20 times, and then "Week 3" repeat 30 times.

Right now I am using this code, but it only allows me to repeat each "Week #" the same amount of times.

```
df$Week <- rep(c("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3"), each = 10)
```

In this example, I have Week 1 repeating 3 times, Week 2 repeating 5 times, and Week 3 repeating 7 times.  How do I specific how many times a specific value repeats?

```
     X   Week  
 1  1.00 Week 1
 2  2.00 Week 1
 3  3.00 Week 1
 4  4.00 Week 2
 5  5.00 Week 2
 6  6.00 Week 2
 7  7.00 Week 2
 8  8.00 Week 2
 9  9.00 Week 3
10 10.0  Week 3
11 11.0  Week 3
12 12.0  Week 3
13 13.0  Week 3
14 14.0  Week 3
15 15.0  Week 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I specific how many times a specific value repeats?

The *`times`* argument. From `?rep`:

> `times`
>   an integer-valued vector giving the (non-negative) number of times to repeat each element if of length `length(x)`, or to repeat the whole vector if of length 1

```
> rep(c("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3"), times = c(10, 20, 30))
# repeats "Week 1" 10 times, "Week 2" 20 times, "Week 3" 30 times
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify exactly how many times you want to repeat "Week #" because sometimes it might not be 10, 20, 30 -- sometimes it can be more random/specific, like, 6, 13, 22

Comment: I just edited to take out the shortcuts I was using and make things clearer. You can change `times = c(10, 20, 30)` to `times = c(6, 13, 22)` or whatever other values you want. I was just using `1:3 * 10` as a lazy way to get to 10, 20, 30.  If you had 10 weeks `1:10 * 10` would be a lot nicer than `c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)`, but for just three it doesn't really matter.

Comment: `seq(10,30,10)` would be another possible choice

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

A generic lists of weeks

```
weeks<-c("Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3")
```

Extract number of repetition from strings

```
repetition<-as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(weeks," "))[seq(2,length(weeks)*2,by=2)])*10
```

Repeat strings

```
Week<-rep(weeks,repetition)
Week
 [1] "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 1" "Week 2"
[12] "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2"
[23] "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 2" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3"
[34] "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3"
[45] "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3"
[56] "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3" "Week 3"
```

Add the info to your data.frame

```
df$Week<-Week
```